# Bundler is trying to install gems off of my root directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler

Ever since I upgrade to Ruby 1.9.3-p392 in `rvm`, things have gone really badly. My project is no longer building, because `bundle install` fails with this error:

```
/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:248:in `mkdir':
Permission denied - /vendor (Errno::EACCES)
```

See that leading slash? That's what I thought, too. So just to test it, I made a `vendor` directory off of my root. And sure enough, when I ran `bundle install` again I ended up with:

```
/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:248:in `mkdir':
Permission denied - /vendor/bundle (Errno::EACCES)
```

For whatever reason, `APP_ROOT/.bundle/config` has a leading slash. For one thing, none of my other projects even have a .bundle directory in them.

What is going on with this environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583422/rvm-gem-install-error). It looks like this will solve your problem. Look in the comments also.

At the command line,

```
$ whoami
=> your username
$ sudo chown -R da:admin /Users/your_username/.rvm
```