# Installing a gem blocked?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sinatra, bundler

(Disclaimer: I am quite new to RubyGems.) I have a Sinatra app where I had a ton of `require` keywords so I wanted to move them into a Gemfile. So far all of them (DataMapper, Prawn, etc) work fine, until I run into this:

```
gem install sinatra-static-assets
```

and it has this error message: `Permission denied - /Users/daryll/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sinatra-static-assets-1.0.4/.gitignore`. I've tried bundler also but there is the same error message.

Tried forcing it via a `sudo gem install` (don't know if that works) and it doesn't seem to work (I am able to run the app but the I get an "`undefined method stylesheet_link_tag`" which means the gem isn't being seen?). What gives?

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem "sinatra", "1.4.3"
gem "sinatra-static-assets", "~> 1.0.4"
gem "json", "~> 1.8.0"
gem "data_mapper", "~> 1.2.0"
gem "dm-sqlite-adapter", "~> 1.2.0"
gem "prawn", "~> 0.12.0"
gem "active_support", "~> 3.0.0"
```

**Config.ru**

```
require 'bundler'
Bundler.require

require './app'
run Sinatra::Application
```

Comment: Can you successfully run `gem install sinatra`?

Comment: @Davidann Yes. I tried running `bundle install` again, same error message.
@AaronGray I have RVM on my machine, what exactly do you mean? (BTW I launch my app via `rackup`).

Comment: A couple things to look into: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18320621/gem-install-rails-error-while-executing-gem-errnoeacces, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17550903/why-do-i-get-a-permission-denied-error-while-installing-a-gem and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583422/rvm-gem-install-error

Comment: @AaronGray Thank you, I was able to install the gem using the third link. However I still get `undefined method stylesheet_link_tag` in my Sinatra app. Any idea why? (Maybe I will be able to debug this better when I sleep.)

Comment: When using RVM do NOT use `sudo`. Even for multi-user installations, `sudo` isn't used after the initial RVM installation. In general, trust the advice on the RVM site over ANY/ALL other sites, because they wrote it and know how it works better than anyone. I'd highly suggest you read through their entire [installation page](http://rvm.io/rvm/install), then their [troubleshooting page](http://rvm.io/support/troubleshooting) as it sound like you have trouble-brewing in your configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will solve your problem: [stackoverflow.com/questions/5583422/rvm-gem-install-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583422/rvm-gem-install-error)

The instructions for sinatra_static_assets suggest running `sudo gem install sinatra-static-assets -s http://gemcutter.org` - have you tried using that?

Also, be sure to follow their instructions on the official page to be sure you have it configured properly - https://github.com/wbzyl/sinatra-static-assets/

Answer (score 0):

Two alternatives to the other answer:

#### 1. Sandbox your gems using Bundler

I use this all the time now:

```
 bundle install --binstubs --path vendor
```

It puts all the gems in the ./vendor directory and all the executables in ./bin. Run it in the project directory e.g.

```
 $ cd /home/myRubyProjects/MyAmazingProject/
 $ bundle install --binstubs --path vendor
```

After that you can just run `bundle install` as the settings are kept in `.bundle`. No need for `sudo` or gemsets or worries about gems from other projects getting trampled or interacting.

#### 2. Sinatra Exstatic Assets

I made a fork of the gem and it changed enough that it [became its own library](https://github.com/yb66/sinatra-exstatic-assets).